# Return value of this from Javascript constructor function, when another constructor is returned

Tags: javascript, this

Why is this pointing to parent Class, and not to window object ?
Not this inside of Klass function.

```
function Class() {
    function Klass() {
        this.color="blue"
    }
    Klass.prototype.value = this; // when called this is pointing to Class
    console.log(this) // "Class"
    return Klass;
}

var One = new Class(); // new constructor is returned
var Two = new One(); // creating new object
Two.value 
    - Class  // why ?
```

Comment: You called `new Class()` which lets `this` inside the function refer to an empty object inheriting from `Class.prototype`. Maybe you wanted to call `var One = Class()`? I'm not sure what you actually want to know...

Comment: I wanted to return constructor and not object from Class function.So the result is another constructor (Klass).

Comment: Yes, that's what the code is already doing. The only difference between `new Class()` and `Class()` in this case is what `this` will refer to. You asked why it refers to an instance of `Class`, it is because you are calling `new Class()` (although I don't see a reason to use `new` here).

Answer (score 1):

```js
Two.value instanceof Class // true
```

Two.value contains instance of Class, not a reference to the Class.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Class() {
    function Klass() {
        this.color="blue"
    }
    Klass.prototype.value = this; // this is in a closure
    console.log(this) // "Class"
    return Klass;
}

var One = new Class(); // new constructor is returned
var Two = new One(); // creating new object
Two.value 
    - Class  // this is always refer to "One"
```